# How to change the processing unit during run time (from GPU to CPU)?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, gpu

In the context of deep neural networks training, the training works faster when it uses the GPU as the processing unit.
This is done by configuring CudNN optimizations and changing the processing unit in the environment variables with the following line (Python 2.7 and Keras on Windows):

```
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "floatX=float32,device=gpu,optimizer_including=cudnn,gpuarray.preallocate=0.8,dnn.conv.algo_bwd_filter=deterministic,dnn.conv.algo_bwd_data=deterministic,dnn.include_path=e:/toolkits.win/cuda-8.0.61/include,dnn.library_path=e:/toolkits.win/cuda-8.0.61/lib/x64"
```

The output is then:

```
Using gpu device 0: TITAN Xp (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN 5110)
```

The problem is that the GPU memory is limited compared to the RAM (12GB and 128GB respectively), and the training is only one phase of the whole flow. Therefore I want to change back to CPU once the training is completed.
I've tried the following line, but it has no effect:

```
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "floatX=float32,device=cpu"
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to change from GPU to CPU and vice-versa during runtime? (technically)
2. If yes, how can I do it programmatically in Python? (2.7, Windows, and Keras with Theano backend).

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible at least for the tensorflow backend. You just have to also import tensorflow and put your code into the following `with`:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
     your code

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
     your code
```

I am unsure if this also works for theano backend. However, switching from one backend to the other one is just setting a flag beforehand so this should not provide too much trouble.